# Moving a right floated div down on a responsive page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to get the result you can see here:
[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/oxzeuu28/) (try resizing the rendered window)

```
<div>
    <div class="pull-right col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
    <p>Content 1</p>
</div>
```

where I have the green box floated right inside the blue one, and the text inside the blue box should continue under the green one when longer.
When the screen is small, though, the green box takes the full width, and I need it to go below the blue one, rather than above as it does now.
I need this on normal/big screens:
[image: Big screen]
and this on small screens:
[image]

If I put the Content 1 < p > above the green < div >, the green box will end up below.
If I try this different approach: [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/2d2v9dbr/),
on small screens it works how I want it to, but on normal screens the text in the blue box won't continue below the green one when longer.
Seems like a stupid problem but I can't find any workaround... Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show screenshot of what you want it to look like? I can't tell based on your question details

Comment: Sure, here they are.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="pull-right col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
<div style="background-color: cyan">
    <p>Content 1<br/>More content</p>
    <div style="background-color: green">
        <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
    </div></div>
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: No, sorry. I added screenshots to the post.

Comment: use media query and provide `display:block` to content 2

Comment: To the green div you mean? Aren't they displayed as block by default? I also tried applying it to the Content 2 p, but can't get any difference...

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'pull-left' on your content element, i added a 'div' to be the content container.

Move to the bottom your content2, so when it's a small screen it will be below

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/1Ln17ugb/4/)**

HMLT

```
<div class="parent"> 
    <div class="pull-left">
        <p>Content 1<br/>More content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right col-xs-12 col-sm-6 green">
        <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
    background-color: cyan;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.green{
    background-color: green;
}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .green{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
.green{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
.green{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like this solution makes the green box go down if there's a long line in the blue one: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1Ln17ugb/2/)

Comment: @Aise i updated my answer, depending on what content will go inside of the 'greenbox' you may need to change other things, i believe you can go on with this

Comment: Thanks for your time, you're being very helpful, but unfortunately this still doesn't work for me. The point is that I have long texts in the boxes, so, while it looks good in the previous example, in fact I can't use it as the first lines are not so short and desappear below the green box:
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1Ln17ugb/5/). I don't want to waste more of my and your time if this is so difficult (or not possible) to fix, I guess I'll just go with some Javascript solution (like moving the green box after the paragraph on small screens), or keep it simple and just use a different layout.